# xamarin.forms Package restore failed

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am using visual studio 15.6.0 version. I have the following SDK Manager installed:

[image]

I am trying to use Google maps in my application. Below is my code on main.xaml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App1"
             xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.Maps;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Maps"
             x:Class="App1.MainPage">

    <maps:Map x:Name="MainMap"></maps:Map>

</ContentPage>
```

I also installed Xamarin.forms.maps. After that I am trying to install Xamarin.playservices.Base ,
 Xamarin.playservices.Basement,
 Xamarin.playservices.maps and
 Xamarin.playservices.taks using nuget. Below is the image for manage nuget pacakges

[image]

I keep getting the below error when I tried to install this through nugget

```
   Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'App1.Android'.
```

Do I need   Xamarin.playservices.Base, Basement, Tasks in order to use Google maps? My main.xaml.cs code looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps;




namespace App1
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            MainMap.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Position(36.89, 10.18), Distance.FromKilometers(5)));
        }
    }
}
```

when I tried to run the application, I don't see any maps although I can see the icon for app1 and when I double click a blank page comes up. My android manifest file looks like below:

[image]

and my android manifest.xml file looks like this

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.co.App1" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <application android:label="$safeprojectname$">
        <meta-data android:label="com.google.android.maps.geo.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaSyDxhj-n96-YaWHibZU2e5BK02U9UzRCnC0" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Below is the compile target version:

[image]

below is the image of the references that are added to my project:

[image]

Comment: Try using version 42.1021.1 of the packages, instead of 60.1142.0

Comment: What is the Compile Target Version set to?

Comment: I think it is set to "use latest platform (android 8.1 Oreo). I put the picture of that in my original post. I think I am looking at the right place for compile target version. I don't see monoandroid in the list.

Comment: I am looking under project -> properties->application. Please let me know if I am looking at the wrong place

Comment: I really need help. Can anyone help me with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I need Xamarin.playservices.Base, Basement, Tasks in order to use Google maps?

Actually, with VS 15.6, there is no need to install `Xamarin.playservices.Base` and other dependencies independently. When you are installing `Xamarin.Forms.Maps` to the native project, the related dependencies will be referenced into your project, and you will be notified by a pop-up dialog:

[image]

Comment: I didn't see those references added under my android references. I put the images of my references in my original post. Can I actually see those in my android applicaton

Comment: These dependencies are hidden under `Xamarin.Forms.Maps` package, so you won't see them under reference, but you can actually use any classes of these dependencies in your project.